# Can't show ng-repeat inside ng-show

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to figure how to show or hide a list of ids and references, filtered by name with an input text.

The problem is that the list of items is going to be very long and I'd like the list to be hidden FIRST then SHOWN and FILTERED whenever I type something in the input that matches an existing item reference.

I tried to add a `NG-SHOW` directive in a `<div>` containing my `NG-REPEAT` but then nothing shows up...
like this:

Here's what I did : http://plnkr.co/edit/HVI7iAHdkLJJhGeN9DT0?p=preview

Commented out the ng-show!

Thx in advance

Comment: just do `<div ng-show="searchInput">` instead of `<div ng-show="showIt(searchInput)">` This will show the list only when `searchInput` has a value

Comment: Awesome! One last thing can I show the list only when searchInput will contain more than 4 caracters for example?

Comment: Yes.  See my answer below but change this:
<ul ng-show="searchInput.length">

to this:

<ul ng-show="searchInput.length == 4">

Comment: Also, ditch the `data-` part. You don't need it for angular stuff. Instead of `data-ng-model` it is just `ng-model`. Same goes for all the other angualr directives

Comment: Thumbs up for ronnie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you don't want the list to show until someone tries to filter the list.  If thats the case, just hide the list until the input has a length.

```
<ul ng-show="searchInput.length">
 <li data-ng-repeat="item in items | filter: searchInput">{{ item.id }} {{ item.ref }}       </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You're welcome.  Just add ng-show="searchInput.length == 4" to display the list on four characters.

Answer (score 0):

http://plnkr.co/edit/HiibcFBahpXdux5YlOrh?p=preview

```
<body>
  <div data-ng-controller="CTController">
    Reference
    <br/>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="searchInput" />
    <!--<div data-ng-show="showIt(searchInput)">-->
    <ul ng-if="searchInput">
      <li data-ng-repeat="item in items | filter: searchInput">{{ item.id }} {{ item.ref }}</li>
    </ul>
    <!--</div>-->
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you only need to show specific items when searched. For this, you don't have to pass value to that function. simple write model name in ng-show to show specific items when searched.

You can check this article for more information: http://blog.hfarazm.com/filters-in-angularjs/

```
<!doctype html>
<html data-ng-app="ColisType">

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='script.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-ng-controller="CTController as abc">
    Reference
    <br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchInput" />
    <div ng-show="searchInput">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter: searchInput">{{ item.id }} {{ item.ref }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```